# Avoid duplicate records created via seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seeding

I have the following  code in my `seeds.rb` to create a record in my simple Rails app.

```
Post.create(
    title: "Unique Title!",
    body: "this is the most amazingly unique post body ever!"
  )
```

When running the `rake db:seed` command it obviously seeds the db with this data.  How do I add a check or safeguard in the code so that it only enters that once, i.e. as a unique?  If I rerun `rake db:seed`, I don't want add that same entry again.

Comment: The title *"Unique Title!"* hints that you should add an uniq index to the `title` column of your `posts` table. Furthermore you might want to add a validation for uniqueness to that attribute to your model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Post.where( title: "Unique Title!",  body: "this is the most amazingly unique post body ever!").first_or_create
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

A way to quickly prevent this is using `find_or_create_by`.

The usage would be like:

```
Post.find_or_create_by(title: "Unique Title!", body: "this is the most amazingly unique post body ever!")
```

Here's the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

Comment: This is good when you aren't creating a bunch of content as an array of objects (JSON-ish). In that case it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a gem like `seed_migration` or `the_gardener` or something else which create versions of the seeds and run these only one time.

most of these creates seedfiles similar to the migration files